# calling setState from an event handler is triggering constructor (reset) in component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a child component and I'm calling setState from an event handler within that child component.  However, when I call setState to set a state variable in this scenario, the constructor of the component gets called which essentially resets that state variable back to the default value.  Looks like calling setState in the child component re-renders the parent component, which in turn re-renders the child component.  Is there a way to code around this scenario?

Comment: Without seeing the code, there's not much we can tell you. If the constructor is rerunning, that must mean the component is remounting. As a guess, remounting may be caused by a react key changing, but again, without code, there's not much we can do.

Comment: If your declared your state inside the child component, changing that state should have no effect on the parent.

Comment: @NicholasTower - good call!  it was an issue with the keys.  Math.random() was being used for child component keys.   I changed the child component keys to {ComponentName}-{selectedRecordId}, and the behavior is much more stable and as expected.  but one weird thing is that I'm having to toggle records - edit works after toggling to first populated record or can go back to default id=0 record after toggle and then edit the default/empty record.  any guesses on what i should look for in this scenario?